# URL paths: to change or not to change

Tags: navigation, urls

I work for a website that allows users to browse and discover live theater.

We offer one experience under the `/shows/city` path where users can browse the complete list of every show in a city. In there they can filter by date and genre, and sort by shows closing soon, opening soon, A-Z, and a few other options.

We're about to introduce an alternative method, where a curated portion of the best of these shows (about 10%) are presented in a Netflix-style list of collections. The aforementioned filters would be absent on this page, but there's a button next to each collection that would bring the user to a filtered view of the `/shows/city` page.

Should we offer the alternative method within the `/shows/` path? Or should it be under a different path since it's a pretty different experience?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound like an alternative, because you only showcase 10% of them. If '/shows' itself isn't used, it makes the most sense to use that for this special showcase. Else, it's also logical to go with '/shows/best'

Also, do you offer anything else other than shows? If all you have are just shows, then you don't need the 'shows' part in the path.